# Fool proof encryption decryption of a text file?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, encryption

Please consider following situation:

1. I place a text file after encrypting it on web for different
   users to download.
2. Each user has a WPF-application on PC which shows the text from file (after decrpyting it) in read only editor.
3. The purpose is that no one without that WPF-application can view the contents of the file.

The problem is with the key needed to decrypt the file. WPF (C#) application can be decompiled to extract key. If a embed key in C++ DLL and call this in C# (to pass key to decryption algo) its again similar to previous situation. Other solutions I can think of have similar risks.

Can you please guide me in this situation? Problem is that I can't get key from web server every time user runs app. It has to be stored on user's PC or within application.

Thank you everyone for your time and patience.

**Edit:**

I am working on an application which reads a file with the constraint that this file should only be opened in my application. So first solution that came to my mind was to encrypt the file and keep the key with in the application or at various places and combine on the fly. These are flawed methods. Please bear in mind that application has to work offline. This approach is easier but not safe as once the file is decrypted into plain text, then it can be shared easily. The intention is to make the contents available to those people who have this application.

The other approach is to have a proprietary format e.g. DRM-protected LIT by Microsoft. A file with this format can be read in Microsoft Reader. This seems to be a bigger task. I need help to know if it is safe as compared to former approach and will protect the copyrighted information in the file or it can be cracked (using any method) easily just like my first mentioned approach. Moreover, will it be a good idea to write this application in C++ as it compiles into machine code which can't be easily converted into source code. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to store some informations on the user's PC and use them in your application, then it is always possible for advanced users to extract them. And embedding the key into C++ DLL wouldn't solve to problem.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption

Comment: I have further explained the question. Moreover, I am not asking for detailed answers. Even if someone can give 4/5 points of one line each, I'll then research myself. Coz that will give me a direction to move.

Answer (score 1):

There is only two solutions to this problem (and neither is 100% secure even then). Both involve "not storing the key in your application".

1. Let the user type the key in.
2. Get the key from a server somewhere.

Make sure that the server is also encrypted using for example https, or someone can decrypt it by scanning the network packets.

Whatever solution you come up with storing a key locally on the machine will be possible to find by omeone that has access to the executable (or DLL or whatever), there is literally no way around that. You can make it more complicated by "hiding" the key in sevreal places and make complicated calculations, but "security by obscurity" only stops people who are impatient with finding the solution.

And even if you don't store the key, someone running the application could stop in a debugger and examine the key as the decryption happens. There literally is no way to make encryption and decryption (in software, at least) entirely "unbreakable by hiding the key" - the key has to be there during the decryption, so it CAN be found.

It then comes down to "how much effort you are willing to spend on making such a process harder", bearing in mind that if the FBI, NSA, GCHQ, KGB or some such puts 100 of their best people on breaking your code, they probably will, no matter what you have come up with. [In fact, they can probably break it by simply running on many machines that just brute-force it open, because these organisations have large clusters available to them, so if it's important to break, that will be a resource for these organisations]. If you are trying to protect from "John Smith" who uses the application, and isn't particularly computer literate, then storing the decryption key in the application itself is perfectly fine. And in between those positions, you have people who, as a hobby, breaks codes in programs. They will give up before the team of 100 government agency workers, but obviously put more effort and skill into it than "John Smith".

Comment: Thanks Mats. Sole reason is to protect copyright information and not allowing its illegal sharing.